# Accessing an addon domain outside public_html

Tags: networking, ip, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting account with a shared IP, and with no domain name added yet. I have uploaded a website in the public_html folder and I can access it by using the shared server's IP and my account username preceded by a ~ :

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/~myuser/
```

I've then created an add-on domain with a folder outside the public_html folder as document root. That means that, in my server's home folder, I have the following folders:

```
cgi-bin
access-logs
(...)
public_ftp
public_html (CAN ACCESS)
myaddondomain.com (TRYING TO ACCESS)
(...)
```

I have tried several combinations (for example: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/~myuser/myaddondomain.com) but I may be missing the point here.

Is it possible to access the myaddondomain.com folder through my web browser by using the shared IP? May I need some sort of server configuration? I would like to test a website this way.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough to implement. I will assume you are using cPanel.

1. Log in to cPanel
   [image: Login]
2. Click `Cron Jobs`
   [image: Cron_Home]
3. Under `Common Settings` select `Once Every Minute`
4. In the command field type this, substituting `user` with your username, `addondomain` with your domain and `addondomainshortcut` with the name of the shortcut `ln -s /home/user/addondomain /home/user/addondomainshortcut`
   [image: Cron]
5. Click OK
6. Open `File Manager`
   [image]
7. Once you see that shortcut, remove the cron job
   [image: check]
8. move the shortcut to `/public_html`
   [image: move]

You can now access the addon domain through `http://url/~user/addondomainshortcut/`